# Test if user has access to a web

Tags: permissions, csom, jsom, access

We are trying to create a function to see if the logged in user has access to a web (subsite), and have come up with the following code;

```
CheckPermissionOnWeb();

function CheckPermissionOnWeb() {
    //context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    context = new SP.ClientContext( '/central/asOne/' );;
    web = context.get_web();

    var currentUser = web.get_currentUser();
    console.log( currentUser );

    context.load( web, 'EffectiveBasePermissions' );

    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate( this, onSuccessMethod ),
        Function.createDelegate( this, onFailureMethod )
    );
};

function onSuccessMethod( sender, args ) {
    if ( web.get_effectiveBasePermissions().has( SP.PermissionKind.viewListItems ) ) {
        jQuery( '#siteListing' ).html( '<h1>YAY! I can access AsOne</h1>' );
    };
};

function onFailureMethod( sender, args ) {
    jQuery( '#siteListing' ).html( '<h1>NO PERMISSIONS TO AsOne</h1>' );
};
```

The issue is, when you do this on a user that does not have access to the that web (subsite) it prompts for the user to log in - where i just want it to "error out".